# How to prove that a random variable is continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Prove that the random variable has a continuous distribution, or, $X$
“is continuous” for short, if and only if $P(X=x)=0$ for any $x$ in $R$.

Can anyone give some hint for this problem?

Comment: Can you describe a relevant property of the function $x \mapsto P[X \le x]$? How would you characterise the rv. as being not continuous?

Comment: Thaks for your nice response. This is the problem from the book "Problems in Probability" by Shiryaev, Albert N. There are no other comments for the condition of the assumption.

Comment: That was addressed as a question for you :-).

Comment: It is just a self-study. I am a beginner in this measure theory and probability theory area. If I have some hints or solutions for this problem or others. I will also share them

Comment: I added some notes below.

Answer (score 1):

The cdf. $F(c)= P[X \le c]$ is a non decreasing function. It is fairly straightforward to show that $F$ is always continuous from the right, that is,
$\lim_{t \downarrow x} F(t) = F(x)$.

There are various definitions of continuity for distributions.

The one you are using is that the distribution is continuous **iff** the cdf. $F$
is continuous as a function.

From the above remark, we see that the distribution is continuous **iff** the cdf. $F$
is continuous from the left.

Suppose $x_n \uparrow x$.
Noting that $\{x\} = \cap_n ((-\infty,x] \setminus (-\infty, x_n] ) $,
we see that $P\{x\} = F(x) - \lim_n F(x_n)$.

It follows that $F$ is continuous at $x$ **iff** $P\{x\} = 0$.

Another, different definition, is that the distribution is continuous **iff**
$F$ is absolutely continuous. For example, the cantor distribution is continuous but not absolutely continuous (cf. singular distributions).

Answer (score 0):

HINT: note that

$$
\Pr[X\le c]-\Pr[X\le c-\delta]= F_X(c)-F_X(c-\delta)
$$

where $F_X$ is the distribution of $X$, and that $\Pr[X=c]=\Pr[X\le c]-\Pr[X<c]$.